# ansible shell escape single and double quotes

Tags: shell, module, escaping, ansible, quotes

I'm trying to execute this command:

```
ps -eo pid,args --cols=10000 | awk '/\/opt\/logstash\/logstash-1.5.3\// && $1 != PROCINFO["pid"] { print $1 }'
```

whith ansible -m shell module (*not* working example):

```
ansible -m shell -a '"'ps -eo pid,args --cols=10000 | awk '/\/opt\/logstash\/logstash-1.5.3\// && $1 != PROCINFO[\'pid\'] { print $1 }' '"' all
```

One of the ways would be to put that into a file, but still it would be nice to run as a command - any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash escaping rules will do:

```
ansible localhost -m shell -a "ps -eo pid,args --cols=10000 | awk '/\\/opt\\/logstash\\/logstash-1.5.3\\// && \$1 != PROCINFO[\"pid\"] { print \$1 }'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Mine alternative version that worked:

```
ansible -m command -a "ps a |grep -E '/opt/logstash/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/jruby' " all --sudo
```

Check if the process are running:

```
ansible -m shell -a "ps aux |grep -E '/opt/logstash/logstash-1.5.3/vendor/jruby'|grep -v -e grep |wc" all
```

Comment: I have to confess to an aversion to grep | grep -v grep.   grep -Ec '/[o]pt..' would obviate the need for both the grep -v and the wc -c.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way (i.e. without having to rewrite the command much or introduce a bunch of escapes) is to use a temporary variable.

Your original command:

```
ps -eo pid,args --cols=10000 \
  | awk '/\/opt\/logstash\/logstash-1.5.3\// && $1 != PROCINFO["pid"] { print $1 }'
```

Corresponding ansible call:

```
x='/\/opt\/logstash\/logstash-1.5.3\// && $1 != PROCINFO["pid"] { print $1 }'; \
  ansible all -m shell -a "ps -eo pid,args --cols=10000 | awk '$x'"
```